# How to make liquid marbles at home?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Some months ago I was reading a bunch of papers about the dynamics of [liquid marbles](http://rspa.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/462/2067/973.full.pdf+html). I was wondering if any of you have worked with them and know how to make them. I bought graphite and tried to cover a water droplet with graphite but without any success.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: What kind of graphite? How fine? What else have you tried? What else have you decided isn't worth trying?

Comment: I don't know how fine. It's the one used to lubricate surfaces. Much smaller than a mm. However I haven't measured it.